# Using 2LO with New Marketplace App and Oauth2

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We have a Marketplace app and using 2LO we have been accessing Contacts , Calendar and user provisioning API's for all users, once the App is installed in a domain from marketplace app.

Now with migrating to Oauth2.0, I couldnt find any documentation or approach to implement 2LO to continue accessing the API's.

Handling the API's with Access token, refresh token of OAuth2.0 will be critical and it will include too many calls ( for verifying the token is still valid or not ).

Could any one help or point to the documentations for implementing 2LO with marketplace apps.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

2-Legged OAuth 1.0 is deprecated and not used with the new marketplace. OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts replace them. See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing